# can't run setup:di:compiler

Tags: magento2, error, permissions

I can't run setup:di:compiler, the error are:

```
Class Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not g  
  enerate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only
```

What i try:

1) Set 777 to generated folder (chmod -R 777 generated/* )
2) Create a user (named "permisos" with a group named "permisos"), assing it on apache 2 evn, restart apache, do sudo permissions to that user, and try the command again
3) run command, put again 777 permisions to generated, run command
4) Delete all caches with c:c and folders in cache at var.

As i see, wen i run command with ROOT user, the 777 permisions change and toe owner of generated/code change to root:root, if i run with "permisos" user i get same error, but users are permisos:permisos

Have any idea on how to solved it?

Extra info: Magento 2.3, Apache server, Google Cloud (all are for test pruposes)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Magento 2.2 and above

the below might sort you out:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {}
```

what is missing is the recursive write permissions and this is made with the s towards the end of the line above

see full docs to set permissions at: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: The error continue. I try also set 777 to all var/www/html folder with chmod -R 777 html but not work

Comment: you might want to empty generated folder first. Make sure ownerships is given to the webserver user.